# [Symfony2]: Cascading element deletion of an entity How to have a life cycle attribute

Tags: entity-framework, symfony, symfony-2.7

I'm using symfony 2.7 as CMF .

I have 2 entity user and Mission . mission have a life cycle attribute (createdBy ,updatedBy).

when i try to delete the user i have this error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`XXXX`.`mission`, CONSTRAINT `FK_19653DBD16FE72E1` FOREIGN KEY (`updated_by`) REFERENCES `fos_user_user` (`id`))

this is my life cycle elément in the entity mission:

```
   /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="created_by", referencedColumnName="id" , onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
private $createdBy;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="updated_by", referencedColumnName="id" , onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
private $updatedBy;
```

thx for help.

Comment: Do you want to delete the missions when the user is delete or set it at null ?

Comment: i want to delete mission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it on your doctrine relation in the user side, something like :

```
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="your\entity\mission", cascade={"delete"})
```

EDIT :

If you can't access the user entity (don't see why you can't ...) you can do something a bit ugly like get the mission attached to the user, delete it then delete the user

Comment: the probléme that i have so many entity with the life cycle and  i can't have this annotation  in entity user

Answer (score 0):

In your user entity: 
 `@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="xx",mappedBy="mission_id",cascade={"persist"})`

In your mission entity :

```
@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User")
@ORM\JoinColumn(name="created_by", referencedColumnName="id" , 
onDelete="CASCADE")
```

Comment: i don't have an annotation inside the user entity